# Is NSData appropriate for large c arrays?

Tags: cocoa, nsdata

I'm reading large FITS images using the CFITSIO library for C. At first, the actual image/pixels are not read in. Only when some sort of operation needs to be done (say, an average of a few images) is the image loaded into memory as a double array. I represent each image as an object of type ImageListing (a custom class). This class knows how to read/write fits files.

To represent a series of images, I use an NSMutableArray inside another class, called ImageStacker. ImageStacker implements methods which can average, subtract, sum the images. Obviously, to do these operations this class needs access to the raw pixels, which it gets by sending the message `returnPixelsFrom:(NSInteger)Row`.

My question is, should I:

1) Read in the pixels in the above mentioned method, but read them into a C array (of type double) thats passed by reference.

OR

2) Should I read in the pixels into a local C array, but then compose a NSData object using `dataWithBytes:length` and return this object from the method.

What advantage does option 2 have over 1? Keep in mind, that when averaging/adding the pixels I will have to use a C array anyway, so isn't it better to keep using purely C arrays for this purpose?

Comment: I'm genuinely curious -- what pointed you at using `NSData` for this?

Comment: Reading the NSData class reference gave me the impression that this is the way to go if we want to treat raw data in Cocoa. But I agree with you, it seems like a pointless exercise in my case because all I'll be doing is making an NSData object out of the data and then decomposing it again when I need to process. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only reason you'd want to use `NSData` is if you needed to hand those bits to a Cocoa class like `NSDictionary` that didn't know how to deal with a plain-C array, or wanted to use Cocoa to archive or serialize the data.

If you're generating (or loading) the bits and doing all the work on them in your custom routines, I say leave it in whatever format suits you best, especially if you're just going to stick the data into an `NSData` and then pull them right back out. However, there may be something I don't know about `NSData` that would make it advantageous to you.

Comment: NSData has _massive_ advantages. Like proper handling of object life times, accessing memory mapped files, reading/writing to files with a single call.